# How was this transaction validated?

Tags: transactions, signature, validation

I'm having trouble understanding how the following transaction was valided (Block 364845 July 2015) :

2c6c27639e79038cf446e795e267dc8abbe96d1f21cdd17518cc6b57ad2d86d9

It has one input, and is redeeming a P2PKH output.

It's ScriptSig is (95 bytes):

**3c**303902153b78ce563f89a0ed9414f5aa28ad0d96d6795f9c6302207cb21ff771e841b5706df6f7e26bbea177d05129b1fe1ec49af65f4bb0ba744a03**21**0265939df6b81b4d5ecb3b913d7013efda1498349b65b61847825c37bfde5b87fe

The **bold** bytes are data-pushes. The second data-push is the public key, it is the first one that I'm having a problem with. It is supposed to be the signature, but I don't understand it, it doesn't even seem to be DER encoded. The s-value seems to be 0x7cb21ff771e841b5706df6f7e26bbea177d05129b1fe1ec49af65f4bb0ba744a and the sighash x03, but I can't read the r-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got confused because you changed the order of signature and public key in scriptSig which consumes P2PKH output.

**First comes the signature, then the public key.** [Here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/107873/140802) you can see the complete list for all standard transactions.

Since the signature is the first data-push in scriptSig, the DER format of the signature in the transaction you specified is as follows:

```
DER sequence:30
sequence_length:39
integer_value:02
length:15
R:3b78ce563f89a0ed9414f5aa28ad0d96d6795f9c63
integer_value:02
length:20
S:7cb21ff771e841b5706df6f7e26bbea177d05129b1fe1ec49af65f4bb0ba744a
```

Comment: Thanks, actually what destabilized me was the unusually low value for r

Comment: @mathboi You're welcome